# PHP Array Deep Child

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [parent] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [parent] => 0
                    [name] => parent
                )

            [name] => child
        )

    [name] => grandchild
)
```

I want to dive very deep, like the following

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [parent] => 0
    [name] => parent
)
```

Max depth following array is unlimited, any idea ?

Can i dive(1) to get array grandchild, dive(2) to get array child, dive(3) to get array parent ? i following this function to calculate the depth of the array

```
function array_depth(array $array) {
    $max_depth = 1;

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $depth = array_depth($value) + 1;

            if ($depth > $max_depth) {
                $max_depth = $depth;
            }
        }
    }

    return $max_depth;
}
```

Comment: First question is what have you tried? I'm rather certain a simple recursive function could do this.

Comment: right sir, just foreach my array and if !is_array base on parent. . but i need dinamic access to level of depth dive(1) to get array grandchild, dive(2) to get array child, dive(3) to get array parent